# c getline skip blank line

Tags: c, line, getline

```
while(getline (&line, &line_size, f) != -1){}
```

> I'm using this function to read line line. But i want to know when i'm reading a blank line. Can someone help?

Comment: Depending on whether `getline()` does or does not return the trailing newline, you can check for the line being 0 or 1 character long.

Comment: define "blank" ? does it mean anything that contains only whitespace or is totally empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so as H2CO3 already mentioned you can use the line length for this:

```
while (getline (&line, &line_size, f) != -1) {

    if (strlen(line) == 1) {
        printf("H2CO3 spotted a blank line\n");
    }

    /* or alternatively */
    if ('\n' == line[0]) {
        printf("Ed Heal also spotted the blank line\n");
    }

    ..
}
```

Comment: @nhenrique glad to hear it. you should thank H2CO3 instead. also you may mark one of the answers as accepted so it won't show up as an open question.

Comment: Why not '\n' == line[0]) and save on the function call.

Comment: @gokcehan - Does `getline` lead to a memory leak?

Comment: @EdHeal assuming the parameters are on stack or you free them afterwards, I don't see how.

Comment: It doesn't work for lines consisting of spaces, which are "blank" by any reasonable standard. Or lines that contain '\r'. Or lines that don't contain '\n'. Since it's so easy to use strspn for this ... -1

Comment: Is a line of spaces blank? You can argue that is not. As to the windows thing/unix thing `if (line[1] == '\n) || ('\r' == line[0] && '\n' == line[1])) ...`

Comment: @JimBalter OP already told that it worked, apparently you don't always need to be generic. I liked your solution but I would say downrate was too much. You should post it as an answer

Comment: @gokcehan - I have rectify this.

Comment: 'You can argue that is not' -- You can argue that 3 is 7, too.

Comment: @gokcehan 'I would say downrate was too much' -- And why would I take your judgment over my own? I downvoted it for what I considered to be good reason.

Comment: @JimBalter I never told you to take my judgement over your own. What I argue is that there should be a consensus about meanings of uprates and downrates, otherwise they make no sense at all. If you hover the downrate button, it says 'this answer is not useful' which is not the case because it already worked for someone. There's also a third option, not voting at all, which I believe would better suit to your standing.

Comment: @JimBalter I understand from your comments that you don't like people posting questions without much effort and I also agree with that. However you probably already voted the question down and that should have been the end of it. Voting the answers down is just being greedy.

Comment: @JimBalter What bothers me the most is that you seem to bring this question up over and over again without any obvious reason. We've already spent much more time on this question than it deserved. If you want to do something useful, you should post your solution as an answer and hope that it would be helpful to someone.  You seem to have some knowledge about this topic so why not just share it?

Comment: @JimBalter You seem to have some contadicting ideas but this is not the place to resolve them. You should try [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead. That's my advice, take it or not..

Comment: @EdHeal I'm including your name here because Jim Balter forgot to do so when he replied to your comment..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define blank line.

Also, because "The getline function reads an entire line from a stream, up to and including the next newline character."

I don't think

```
strlen(line) == 1
```

is portable, as Win/DOS and Unix use different convention for EOL. Also, the EOF may occur before an EOL character is done. So really, you need to define a function maybe something like

```
int is_blank_line(char *line, int line_size)
{
   return line_size == 0 || is_eol(line)
}
```

where is_eol is defined for the platform you are on. This is where you can put in whitespace can be in a blank line, etc.

So you'd get something like:

```
int is_eol(char *line)
{
...
     return result;
}
...
int is_blank_line(char *line, int line_size)
{
  return line_size == 0 || is_eol(line)
}
...
while (getline (&line, &line_size, f) != -1) {
    if (is_blank_line(line, line_size)) {
        printf("blank line spotted\n");
    }
...
}
```

Comment: `if (line[strspn(line, " \t\v\r\n")] == '\0') // line is blank` works fine. (\v for old times sake, though I haven't seen one for decades.)